# Select array element from Spark Dataframes split method in same call?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm splitting an HTTP request to look at the elements, and I was wondering if there was a way to specify the element I'd like to look at in the same call without having to do another operation.

For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn

df.select(fn.split(df.http_request, '/').alias('http'))
```

gives me a new `Dataframe` with rows of arrays like this:

```
+--------------------+
|                http|
+--------------------+
|[, courses, 26420...|
```

I want the item in index 1 (courses) without having to then do another `select` statement to specify `df.select(df.http[1])` or whatever.  Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you could define a `UDF`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def getter(column, index):
    return column[index]

getterUDF = udf(getter, StringType())

df.select(getterUDF(split(df.http_request, '/').alias('http'), lit(1)))
```

You could also use the `getItem` method recommended by @max

```
df.select(F.split(df.http_request, '/').alias('http').getItem(1))
```

Comment: Using a python UDF will lead to poor performance. The solution with getItem would be preferred.

Answer (score 14):

Use [getItem](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.getItem). I'd say don't use python UDF just to make the code looks prettier - it's much slower than native DataFrame functions (due to moving data between python and JVM).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(F.split(df.http_request, '/').alias('http').getItem(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using selectExpr:

`df.selectExpr("http[1] as http_2nd_item")`